# Snips-nlu intent is returning empty intent json after following quick start

Tags: python-3.x, pip, dependencies, chatbot

I am using the snips-nlu library on a windows 10 machine.

I was able to successfully install it using `pip install snips-nlu` and then install the language with `snips-nlu download en`.
My `example.py` file looks as follows:

```
engine = SnipsNLUEngine(resources=load_resources('snips_nlu_en')) # this works for me
# engine = SnipsNLUEngine(resources=load_resources('en')) # this throws errors about en not being installed even after installing them

with io.open("dataset.json") as f:
    dataset = json.load(f)

engine.fit(dataset)
parsing = engine.parse("Are there holidays next week in botswana?")
print(json.dumps(parsing, indent=2))
```

When execute I get the following output:

```
{
  "input": "Are there holidays next week in botswana?",
  "intent": {
    "intentName": null,
    "probability": 0.4607009138432084
  },
  "slots": []
}
```

My yaml file looks as follows:

```
# ask for country holidays
---
type: intent
name: holidayQuestion
slots:
  - name: country
    entity: snips/country
  - name: date
    entity: snips/datetime
utterances:
  - What holidays is it [date] in [country]?
  - Is it a holiday in [country]?
  - Is it a holiday [date] in [country]?
  - Is it a [country] holiday [date]?
  - Holiday [date] in [country]?
  - Holiday [date] [country]?
  - Holiday [country]?
```

Which I convert to json file with `snips-nlu generate-dataset en dataset.yaml > dataset.json`.

When I execute my python file it would complain with:

```
FileNotFoundError: No data found for the 'snips/country' builtin entity in language 'en'. You must download the corresponding resources by running 'python -m snips_nlu download-entity snips/country en' before you can use this builtin entity.
```

I executed it using admin rights on windows cmd but It still returns empty slots and no intentName. Can someone help or  explain to me what is happening. I have tried to uninstall pip, python and all packages, restart computer and clear and python/pip related environment variables. But no dice.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in order to avoid running commands using admin rights, you should run everything in a [virtual environment](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/).

Once running in a virtualenv, prior to using `snips-nlu` in your use case, you have to install the english resources and the `snips/country` built-in entity:

```
python -m snips_nlu download en 
python -m snips_nlu download-entity snips/country en
```

This should normally download and link the corresponding resources, so that they are accessible by the `snips-nlu` library in a default location.
It is possible that these two commands fail if you are not running in a virtualenv because of permissions errors.

After that, you can try to play with your dataset using the CLI:

```
> python -m snips_nlu train dataset.json nlu_engine
Create and train the engine...
Persisting the engine...
Saved the trained engine to nlu_engine
```

Then:

```
> python -m snips_nlu parse nlu_engine
Enter a query (type 'q' to quit): Are there holidays next week in botswana?
{
  "input": "Are there holidays next week in botswana?",
  "intent": {
    "intentName": "holidayQuestion",
    "probability": 0.7427372869733698
  },
  "slots": [
    {
      "entity": "snips/datetime",
      "range": {
        "end": 28,
        "start": 19
      },
      "rawValue": "next week",
      "slotName": "date",
      "value": {
        "grain": "Week",
        "kind": "InstantTime",
        "precision": "Exact",
        "value": "2019-12-02 00:00:00 +01:00"
      }
    },
    {
      "entity": "snips/country",
      "range": {
        "end": 40,
        "start": 32
      },
      "rawValue": "botswana",
      "slotName": "country",
      "value": {
        "kind": "Country",
        "value": "Botswana"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Can you share the version of `snips-nlu` that you are using ?
If possible, you should update to the latest available one.